# Почему эсперанто среднего рода?

Tags: род-существительного

Ведь названия языков в русском языке относятся к мужскому роду? (фиджи, фарси, суахили, свази, хинди, урду, пушту, дари, кечуа тд.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я думаю, что средний род у эсперанто -  это устаревающий вариант. У Ушакова (38-40 год) указан только средний род, у Ожегова уже и средний, и мужской.  Но существительные  среднего и мужского рода на-о (е) относятся к одному типу склонения, поэтому фактически в речи не различаются формы ни формы прилагательных, к ним относящихся, ни местоимений (кроме именительного падежа).  Говорил на нем, (ср.?м.?), о знаменитом (ср.? м.?). Просмотрев некоторые статьи об эсператно (включая статью Толстого), так и не поняла, каким же фактически (не в словаре) был род этого существительного.  Я считаю слово эсперанто мужского рода.

Comment: Вообще разница есть. Ср.: крепкий кофе, вкусное кофе.
В [корпусе русского языка][1] есть аналогичные примеры фраз со словом эсперанто. Можно покопать. Но мне кажется более естественным, если считать, что "эсперанто" - среднего рода.

[1]:http://search.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&spd=&text=lexgramm&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&parent1=0&level1=0&lex1=&gramm1=A&sem1=&sem-mod1=sem&sem-mod1=sem2&flags1=&m1=&parent2=0&level2=0&min2=1&max2=1&lex2=%FD%F1%EF%E5%F0%E0%ED%F2%EE&gramm2=&sem2=&sem-mod2=sem&sem-mod2=sem2&flags2=&m2=

Comment: Ну я и говорю же - кроме именительного падежа.  Внимательно читайте!

Comment: Ларf, благодарю за интересный ответ!!

Answer (score 1):

На сайте "Грамота.ру" я тоже прочел, что эсперанто относится к мужскому и среднему роду. Меня это удивило, так как в юности я занимался изучением этого языка, неплохо владел им, был однажды на международном слете эсперантистов, но никогда не слышал, чтобы это слово употреблялось в среднем роде. Не могу придумать ни одной соответствующей фразы: интересный эсперанто, владеть языком эсперанто, богатый на языковые формы эсперанто. Кстати, и на "Грамота.ру" нет примеров употребления этого слова в среднем роде.

Comment: Мне  кажется,  что  слово  "эсперанто"  ближе  к  именам  собственным  и,  к  тому  же,   не  склоняется,  зато  ключевое  "язык"  мужского  рода.  Поэтому  считать,  что  эсперанто  мужского  рода  вполне  естественно.

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, слово это ближе к мужскому роду, что соответствует его лексическому значению "международный искусственно-созданный язык"